# Selecting multiple photos from camera roll

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building a simple app to take pictures of events in React Native. and am stuck on a problem.

I want to submit a photo album to a database to be displayed later. The album will include -- Album Name, Album Description, and Photos... but I'm having a hard time visualizing how to select multiple photos from the camera roll, manipulate them, submit them to a db.

I tried to figure out an order of how I would do accomplish this..

1. Create new event
2. Add event name
3. Add event description
4. Click button > Open Gallery
5. Select Multiple photos
6. Save photos to cache and display thumbnails in "Preview" component
7. Submit "Event" and photos to DB.

Am I even close? Any link to an article, or anything to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can these two libraries to easily complete your task.

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker ( For selecting multiple images from camera roll)

https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob (For uploading images )

Comment: react-native-image-picker doesn't support selecting multiple images at a time. However, [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) does.